# Elasticsearch documents not showing up or updating without routing set

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

So I have a couple of documents (5) that I'm creating and trying to update. They are all similar but after I've inserted them into elasticsearch only one of them responds to a simple query of

```
curl localhost:9200/myindex/posts/:id
```

where :id is a stand-in for the _id number in elasticsearch. The others give me a

```
{"_index":"myindex","_type":"post","_id":":id","exists":false}
```

however whenever I do the query like this

```
curl localhost:9200/myindex/posts/:id?routing=3
```

the results are returned.

This wouldn't be so much of a problem but, I'm trying to do some partial updates using Tire like this

```
Tire.index('myindex'){ update 'post', id, :doc => { :doc_body => content } }
```

and the updates aren't showing up for the items that cannot be found without specifying a routing number.

I just want to understand why elasticsearch is behaving this way.

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered that, because I'm using routing, I have to write the update like this

```
 Tire.index('myindex'){ update 'post', id, { :doc => { :doc_body => content } } { :routing => routing_id } }
```

the cool thing is that if you use Tire to do the search it will automatically, find the document using routing.

so

```
Tire.search('myindex'){ query { string '_id:xxx' } }.results
```

will return results where

```
curl localhost:9200/myindex/posts/xxx
```

*might* not

What I still don't understand why some documents show up with a normal get request and others don't after indexing :\